# How to create a Logger object using Lombok?

Tags: slf4j, lombok

If I use **`Logger`** class then I can create a logger object like this:

```java
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAccessDeniedHandler.class);
```

Now my question is how can I create an object using **Lombok**. I want to invoke `info()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Lombok comes with various log annotations that init a `log` instance for you
[More information here](https://projectlombok.org/features/log)

Choose an annotation corresponding to your logger library and annotate your class with it.

In my project, I use `@Slf4j`